# Receives one integer and returns the factorial of the number passed

Tags: java, package, factorial

Creating two separate packages mathematics and Application. With a class called MathHelper and Application in either one. I need to add static method tothe MathHelper.java class called    factorial(int) that receives one integer and returns the factorial of the number    passed. A main method is added to application called and calls the Mathhelper.factorial. This is the code i have so far...

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

       System.out.println(MathHelper.doubleInt((9)));   
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MathHelper {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
    }
    public static int fact(int factNum) {
        if (factNum==1) {   
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return factNum + (fact(factNum - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right general idea, but the `+` needs to be `*` - factorial means multiplying a whole lot of numbers together, not adding them.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate factorial using:

### loops:

```
public long fact(int factNum) {
    long fact = 1;
    for (int iteration = 2; iteration <= factNum; iteration++) {
        fact = fact * iteration;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

### streams:

```
public long fact(int factNum) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(1, factNum)
            .reduce(1, (long fact, long iteration) -> fact * iteration);
}
```

### recursion:

```
public long fact(int factNum) {
    if (factNum <= 2) {
        return factNum;
    }
    return factNum * fact(factNum - 1);
}
```